# how do I solve the tkinter directory problem

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a video file conversion code using tkinter and ffmpeg, but when using the tkinter command to get the folder directory it gives an error when it finds a folder that has separation between the words.

This is my code:

```
import os
import pathlib
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
path     = filedialog.askdirectory()

print(filename)
print(path)

#os.system('gif2webp ' + pa + ' -o ' + (pe + './Test.gif'))

os.system('ffmpeg -i {} {}'.format(filename, path))
messagebox.showinfo(title="Done", message="Done")
```

And it is this error that appears:

**C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/Test : No such file or directory**

the path is incomplete, because there is a space in the folder name and he does not recognize the path, if you can help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same as you would do in a terminal. Use `""`

```
os.system('ffmpeg -i "{}" "{}"'.format(filename, path))
```

**Or**, escape the spaces with `\`:

```
path = path.replace(" ", "\ ")
```

Or, use the newer and recommended `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", filename, path])
```